# How enable Typescript typing in Vue template for data from Apollo (VS Code)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, apollo, vue-cli

- Created an application via Vue Cli with TS.
- Added Apollo (vue-cli-plugin-apollo) with examples (server and client).
- By the scheme and query it generated an interface

  src/graphql/types/files.ts:

  ```
  export interface files_files {
    __typename: "File";
    id: string;
    path: string;
    filename: string;
    mimetype: string;
    encoding: string;
  }

  export interface files {
    files: (files_files | null)[] | null;
  }
  ```
- src/components/ApolloExample.vue:

  ```
  <template>
  ...
    <div
      v-for="file of files"
      :key="file.id"
      class="image-item"
    >
  ...
  </template>
  ...
  <script lang="ts">
  import Vue from 'vue';

  import FILES from '../graphql/Files.gql';
  import { files_files as IFile, files as IFiles } from @/graphql/types/files';

  export default Vue.extend({
    data() {
      return {
        files: [] as IFile[] // its OK to typing {{file.id}} in template
      };
    },

    apollo: {
      files: () => FILES,
    }
  ...
  ```

  But I want to set the type of something like

  ```
   files: [] as IFiles['files']
  ```

[Code on GitHub](https://github.com/alukos/vue-apollo-ts)